# .eps file not generated using epslatex

Tags: eps, gnuplot

I am trying to do a plot using `epslatex` interface of gnuplot where I am using latex command for labelling the y-axis and then include the plot 
in another TeX file. I am writing the following steps but somehow the `.eps` file is not generated, only the `.tex` file is generated. Please help.

```
reset
set terminal epslatex
set term postscript colour enhanced 
set term postscript eps enhanced 26
set output "pb_sp_I=6.tex"


set style data lines
set size 1,1
set origin 0,0
set multiplot
set size 1,1
set origin 0,0
set log

set xlabel "t" font "Times-Roman,30"
set ylabel "$P_t(\\ell)$" 

set format y  "10^{%L}"
set format x  "10^{%L}"

set xr [0.1:10000]
set yr [0.000001:1.2] 

p 'sp_I=6.out' u 1:2 w l title 'I=6' lc 1 lw 2, 1800/x**1.5 lw 2 title 't^{-1.5}', 1.7/x**0.5 lw 2 title 't^{-0.5}'
```

I removed the line

```
set term postscript eps enhanced
```

and it is now producing 2 files, `pb_sp_I=6.eps` and `pb_sp_I=6.tex`. Then I converted EPS to PDF. I included the `.tex` file above in another `.tex` file, say `a.tex`, by writing the following :

```
\begin{center}
\input{pb_sp_I=6.tex}
\end{center}
```

Then I compile a.tex using the command :

```
pdflatex a.tex
```

But the output contains the figure file only with the axes, tics, lines but the
y-axis labeling in latex (`$P_t(\\ell)$`) is not there. Please advise if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Your `gnuplot` script has many flaws:

- you can use only one terminal, so the `set term postscript` lines should be removed;
- avoid using underscores in your files, because they will cause problems;
- the `multiplot` mode should be closed and the output should be reset, otherwise the output file won't be closed;
- as pointed out by [Christoph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154820/eps-file-not-generated-using-epslatex#comment354854_154879), the `set origin`s and `set size`s are useless;
- you have to wrap dollar signs around all labels, otherwise `^` will throw errors.

This is a revised version of your `gnuplot` script:

```
reset
set terminal epslatex color colortext
set output "pbspI=6.tex"

set style data lines
set multiplot
set log

set xlabel "$t$"
set ylabel '$P_\ell(t)-P_\ell(\infty)$'

set format y  '$10^{%L}$'
set format x  '$10^{%L}$'

set xr [0.1:10000]
set yr [0.000001:1.2] 

plot 'sp_I=6.out' u 1:2 w l title '$\ell=6,N=20$' lc 1 lw 2, \
     1800/x**1.5 lw 2 title '$t^{-1.5}$', \
     1.7/x**0.5 lw 2 title '$t^{-0.5}$'
unset multiplot
set output
```

This is the `.tex` file in which the picture will be included:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \input{pbspI=6.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @S.D do you mind marking the answer as accepted?  This will remove it from the unanswered queue. Thank you `:-)`.

Comment: Not at all ! :-D

Comment: I made some changes in the revised version of the gnu postscript by Sir giordano. They are 1.set terminal epslatex color colortext 2. set ylabel "$P_\\ell(t)-P_\\ell(\\infty)$" 3.plot title as "$\\ell=6\\,N=10$". Again I get 2 files but the tex file is not generated properly I guess. The error I am getting is File `pbspI=6' not found and      \put(0,0){\includegraphics{pbspI=6}} at line no.103 of tex file. Kindly advise.

Comment: @S.D I updated the answer with your changes, excluding the third because I didn't get it (which title do you want to change?).  You say that running the `gnuplot` script generates two files, which?  `pbspI=6.tex` and `pbspI=6.eps` (this file should be converted to PDF, if you have a recent TeX Live distribution this will be done automatically)?

Comment: I wanted to write: plot 'sp_I=6.out' u 1:2 w l title '$\\ell=6,N=20$' lc 1 lw 2. Yes the two files are pbspI=6.tex and pbspI=6.eps. These 2 files are generated but .tex file is not properly compiled. I have inserted it in another tex file a.tex the way you suggested. Ok I am converting eps file to pdf .

Comment: @S.D does the updated answer help you?

Comment: Some other remarks: You can omit all those `set size` and `set origin` stuff. And you should use the `standalone` terminal option. Last point: for convenience, at the end of the document you can write a `system('latex pbspI=6.tex && dvips pbspI=6.dvi && ps2pdf pbspI=6.ps && pdfcrop --margins 1 pbspI=6.pdf pbspI=6.pdf')`. If you're using Windows you must split that single `system` call in one call for each command.

Comment: Sir, Giordano, sorry for being too late in replying, yes your answer helped me.